# Passing arguments within an array Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, arguments

Here's my problem: I want to use a routine with a dynamic number of arguments. For instance, here's my sub:

```
dynamic_sub($firstMandatoryArgment, "second argument", $thirdArgument);
```

I can call dynamic_sub with any number of arguments (but some are mandatory). In my program, the number of arguments depends on the context. So I want to write something like that:

```
my @args = ($firstMandatoryArgment, "second argument", $thirdArgument, ...);

dynamic_sub(@args);
```

The thing is I can't rewrite dynamic_sub(), so I got to find a way to put my arguments into an array, and then call dynamic_sub() with my array of arguments. Of course @args should be interpreted as many arguments, and not as an array ;)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You *did* put your arguments into an array. What's the problem?

Comment: If all arguments are scalars, there is no problem. If one parameter is an array, you have to be careful when you 'shift' your arguments to local variables in the method. You then could use references. But what is your question??????

Comment: Well, it works. I've made a typo :(

Comment: Passing several options as array to a sub is not a good design. Mixing up the order of arguments or adding new probably even mandatory options will sooner or later lead to failure. Better pass the arguments as a hash reference `{ optionA => $valueA , optionB => $valueB ...}`. You can check the existence of an option with `exists $hash_ref->{key}`.

Comment: You don't need to use a hashref to use named arguments in Perl.  Assign `my %args = @_;` and you're good to go, without needing to type `{}` around your parameter lists.

Answer (score 4):

In Perl, subroutines take a *list* of arguments, which is internally assigned to the array `@_`. Therefore, in most cases, calling a sub with an array, or with a list of values, is the same thing.

The one exception is when the subroutine uses *prototypes*:

```
sub without_prototypes  { say "@_" }
sub with_prototypes ($) { say "@_" }

my @args = 1 .. 5;

without_prototypes(@args); # @args is used in list context, prints "1 2 3 4 5\n".
with_prototypes(@args);    # @args is used in scalar context, prints "5\n" (length).
&with_prototypes(@args);   # the & disables prototypes; prints "1 2 3 4 5\n".
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that can be passed as arguments is a list of scalars, so

```
my @args = ($firstMandatoryArgment, "second argument", $thirdArgument, ...);
dynamic_sub(@args);
```

is the same thing as

```
my @args = ( $firstMandatoryArgment, "second argument", $thirdArgument, ... );
dynamic_sub($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], ...);
```

If the sub (stupidly) uses prototypes to override this behaviour, you can override the prototype use `&`:

```
&dynamic_sub(@args);
```